# Get input layer extent as new GeoJSON polygon on the command line

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr, extents, command-line

Starting from a GeoJSON file containing a country boundary polygon, I would like to obtain a rectangular approximation: another GeoJSON consisting of the bounding box/envelope of the original polygon. This seems simple enough to be possible from the command line, so I was thinking of using ogr2ogr (other options also welcome). But I cannot seem to find a command to do this. Can this be done without getting too cumbersome?

With ogrinfo, it's possible to get the layer extent, but it does not generate a geometry file.

The GeoJSON driver also has a WRITE_BBOX option, but that's just additional info and has no impact on the actual geometry.

Comment: This may help https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-spat ?

Comment: @Nil I don't see how that helps. This selects features based on a rectangle.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong link. http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#calculate-envelope-of-a-geometry. However this one would not help much either as it is not commandline

Comment: Do you want the bbox of one selected polygon or the whole layer?

Comment: In my case, the layer only consists of a single multipolygon, so both would be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the GDAL SQLite dialect https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html and ST_Envelope function of SpatiaLite, perhaps together with ST_Union http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

BBOX of one selected feature. First a test with ogrinfo:

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select st_envelope(geometry) from mod limit 1" mod.json
INFO: Open of `mod.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-34.786396, 0.417717) - (-31.168008, 2.388746)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Geometry Column = st_envelope(geometry)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  POLYGON ((-34.7863959482279 0.417716555831419,-31.1680084250499 0.417716555831419,-31.1680084250499 2.38874622033402,-34.7863959482279 2.38874622033402,-34.7863959482279 0.417716555831419))
```

Conversion into GeoJSON with ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -lco RFC7946=YES -dialect sqlite -sql "select st_envelope(geometry) as bbox from mod limit 1" bbox_out.json mod.json
```

GeoJSON from the envelope of the whole layer:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -lco RFC7946=YES -dialect sqlite -sql "select st_envelope(st_union(geometry)) as bbox from mod" bbox_out.json mod.json
```

Comment: I should have thought of the SQLite dialect. Thanks!
But shouldn't the envelope and the union be swapped in the last statement? A union of bounding boxes looks strange. Swapping them would give the bounding box of the whole layer, I think.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing with a layer that had only one geometry and the result looked perfect :)

Comment: Yeah, with one feature both statements should be equivalent. Thanks for updating :)